# How to remove elements in a drop down inside a div element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I want to remove elements in a dropdown, the example of the HTML code is below and I need to select elements by div class "woo-vpf-field-make" then select the name "make" and then option value "73483".

I hope that makes sense :)

```
<div class="woo-vpf-field-make">
  <select name="make">
    <option value="">Select Make</option>
    <option value="70281">BMW</option>
    <option value="73483">Fiat</option>
    <option value="73923">Ford</option>
    <option value="71367">Mini</option>
    <option value="75988">Opel / Vauxhall</option>
    <option value="74715">Volkswagen</option>                   
  </select>
</div>
```

Below is the JavaScript code that I wrote, but seems like it could be lot better :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name^="make"]').children("option[value^=" + "73483" + "]").remove();
    $('select[name^="make"]').children("option[value^=" + "73923" + "]").remove();
    $('select[name^="make"]').children("option[value^=" + "75988" + "]").remove();
    $('select[name^="make"]').children("option[value^=" + "74715" + "]").remove();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add option value in array .And remove the element using forEach based  on array value

```js
var r_arr = ["73483", "73923", "75988", "74715"];
$(document).ready(function() {
  r_arr.forEach(function(value) {
    $('select[name^="make"]').find("option[value^=" +value+ "]").remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="woo-vpf-field-make">
  <select name="make">
    <option value="">Select Make</option>
    <option value="70281">BMW</option>
    <option value="73483">Fiat</option>
    <option value="73923">Ford</option>
    <option value="71367">Mini</option>
    <option value="75988">Opel / Vauxhall</option>
    <option value="74715">Volkswagen</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an `id` to your dropdown

```
$("#select_id option[value='73483']").remove();
```

Comment: I can't modify it, it comes from a plugin :(

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **find()** function to search your value that remove it

```
$('select[name^="make"]').find("option[value^=" +value+ "]").remove();
```

or You can assign a Id to your select than it will be more easy to find

```
$("#id option[value=" +value+ "]").remove();
```